# MongoDB - find only elements with boolean false from Schema model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema, mongoose-populate

I'm unsing MongoDB and NodeJS
and I'm trying to find all tasks with done: false to display on Dashboard.
I'm sorting by the newest to oldest and with a limit of 4 to send and display, but it's sending all tasks and I want that send only with the done: false (this means the tasks are not checked:done:true) but I don't know how to put that in options of populate..

**my Tasks Schema model:**

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

let taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    tasktitle: String,
    taskcomment: String,
    project: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Project'
    }],
    user: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    done: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tasks', taskSchema);
```

**my Tasks Controller:**

```
exports.render_pending_tasks = (req, res) => {
let userid = req.user._id;

  User.findById(userid).populate({ path: 'tasks', options: { sort: { _id: -1 }, limit: 4 } })
      .exec((err, tasks) => {
         if (err) {
             console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.send(tasks);
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: Use match option `{ match: { done: false }}`

Comment: yeah! that's it! thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate on basis of condition in mongoose, mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002835/populate-on-basis-of-condition-in-mongoose-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` option inside the populate function

```
User.findById(userid)
 .populate({
  match: { done: false },
  path: 'tasks',
  options: { sort: { _id: -1 }, limit: 4 }
})
```